# Move form entries between Wordpress Gravity Forms

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a tournament with multiple divisions and multiple forms for which I use `gravity forms`.

There are times when someone requests to be changed to a different division. However, I am unable to move the competitor from one division to another in gravity forms, as the divisions are each using a different form ID (and they have still not developed a method for helping with this).

How would I go about moving a **SINGLE ENTRY** from one gravity form to another forms entry list please.

We have many teams at the tournament, so mass export and import is not what i am looking to achieve. Its about being able to move a single entry from one list of entries in one form to another forms list of entries?

ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Even a simple "use this method" in general terms will help me greatly. Would I use some form of JQuery fiddle, a php script, an sql script or what please as **Import Entries** is not available currently in GF

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, but instead maybe you shold design your form to include all types of submissions logic. I mean you can put a drop-down field at the beginning of your form. Then you can use https://gravityview.co/ to edit your single entry field.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this which i am using in one of my current projects for http://projects.dzign-r.com.au and that is,

1) export both of the the forms (i.e the one from which you need the field to move and the other to which you need this field to be moved to) and it exports these as json files

2) search for the field ID that you need to be moved to another form, cut its json code from the json file and paste it in the other form's json file where you need it to be moved to

3) then import the form back. and test it to make sure it works as you want it, (as a caution you may change the field ID after you paste it in new form to be something which is not used in this form already).

4) once u see everything is fine u may just delete the old form?